# change position of rotationpoint from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to draw some element in a canvas.
I also used clipping section. So the user is only able to see the clipped section.

The issue is, some section is near to the top of the clipping area. So when the user selects that object, then they are not able to see the rotation point.

See this Image: 
[image]

I have no idea how to changethe  position of that rotation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true
```

Instead of moving the point. You should have controls visible outside clipping area if they are still on the canvas.

This is not really an answer for "change position of rotating point" is more fore "make the controls visible outside clipping area" but as of now changing the rotating point is possibile only modifing the library and with a lot of complexity.